# how to know when takeWhile is stop?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I using takeWhile operator to dispach action while the inProgress is true.

When the isProgress is false I want to write to the console "done".

So I write this code:

```
 interval(5 * 1000)
  .pipe(
   withLatestFrom(this.product$),
   takeWhile(([intervalValue, product]) => product.inProgress),
   tap(([intervalValue, product]) => { this.store.dispatch(loadProduct(()) })
  ).subscribe(...)
```

I using interval to call every 5 seconds and update the proudct. when I update the product the inProgress is false so it stops. but how I do something when the takeWhile is stop?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options.

1. `takeWhile` has an optional `inclusive` parameter that when set to `true` will emit the first itme that failed the condition. You could leverage it to do something in the last notification i.e. when the progress is `false`.

```js
interval(5 * 1000).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.product$),
  takeWhile(([intervalValue, product]) => product.inProgress, true),
  tap(([intervalValue, product]) => { this.store.dispatch(loadProduct(()) })
).subscribe(
  ([intervalValue, product]) => {
    if (!product.inProgress) {
      console.log('done')
    }
  },
  err => { }
);
```

2. Or `takeWhile` actually completes the observable stream when the predicate fails. So you could do what you wish in the subscription's `complete` callback.

```js
interval(5 * 1000).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.product$),
  takeWhile(([intervalValue, product]) => product.inProgress),
  tap(([intervalValue, product]) => { this.store.dispatch(loadProduct(()) })
).subscribe(
  ([intervalValue, product]) => { },
  err => { },
  () => console.log('done');
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`interval()` emits indefinitely so the only way your chain is completed is because of `takeWhile` so you can use the `complete` notification in `tap()` or in `subscribe()` for this:

```
tap({
  next: v => ...,
  complete => /* complete */
})
```

or like this:

```
subscribe({
  next: v => ...,
  complete => /* complete */
})
```

Comment: the problem with this answer is the console in complete is run in the next cycle and the property is already changed. I have a spinner that show when `inProgress`  is true. so it look like the spinner disappear and after 3/5 seconds the console/notification is happens.. so how to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're describing. Are you sure you're triggering change detection? Otherwise, can you make a stackblitz demo?